# What function do I use to compare 2 set of data?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to find a formula to do this comparison:

If the data in cells A2 and B2 exist in Columns C and D write "Match"; if not, "NO Match".

Comment: you mean in any row of column C and any row of column D, can you give example

Comment: You can use If with Match

Comment: It isn't clear whether a match is the independent existence of both values anywhere in columns C and D, or only if they are on the same row in the same order.

Answer (score 0):

For example, the **array formula**:

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A2&B2,C1:C8&D1:D9,0)),"no match","match")
```

[image]

**Array formulas** must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

*This formula requires a side-by-side match.*